# how to get touch coordinates in an image then draw a markup icon and its content in a popover view

Tags: iphone, image, touch, coordinates, markup

I would like to built an iPhone/iPad application to show large images (in a scrollView or something else which support dragging and zooming) that allow user to:

- Touch some where in the image to markup and leave comment
- User can tap on that markup icon/button to view comment in a popOverView
- Edit comment or remove that markup

So I want to ask that:

- How can I get the touch coordinates in image (not screen)?
- How can I draw a markup icon/button at touch point in the image and it would follow image even when dragging, zooming since the image is really large, maybe up to 8000x6000 pixels?
- How can I display comment/note when user touch on markup icon/button in a view like popOverview in iPad?
- Save and load these information.

It is nearly similar to tagging functionality of Facebook App in iPhone.

Any help is appreciated, thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 . You subclass the UIImageView and override the touch methods:

> - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
> - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
> - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
> - (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

2 . You add and UIButton to the UIImageView `[yourImageView addSubview:yourButton];` then set the center of your button to touch coordinates.

3 . Just present an popover when user taps on an button. (You can set tag property for buttons to know which button is tapped)

4 . Save data to an plist to documents directory if is not to complex ore use core data.

Good Luck. Just post comments if you need more help.

Edit: 
you need to set the user userInteractionEnabled to YES for the UIImageView.

> userInteractionEnabled A Boolean value that determines whether user
>   events are ignored and removed from
>   the event queue.
>
> @property(nonatomic,
>   getter=isUserInteractionEnabled) BOOL
>   userInteractionEnabled Discussion This
>   property is inherited from the UIView
>   parent class. This class changes the
>   default value of this property to NO.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and
>   later. Declared In UIImageView.h

From [UIImageView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/userInteractionEnabled)

Comment: Hi Terente, I don't know why but it seems the UIButton in UIImageView which be nested in UIScrollView does not work, I already set button center but does not get response when tap on it. But when I add button as subview of ScrollView, it does, please help me